# remote desktop connection doesn't work while using vpn

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I connect from my laptop to my wireless connection, run VPN to connect to my office's network, then try to use remote desktop connection to see my office's computer desktop. It always fails.

Some details:
1) If I do the same using my neighbor's wireless network, remote desktop connection works fine.
2) If I connect with my wireless network, I can't use remote desktop connection, but I can see and use the files on my office computer (by running \computername\c$)
3) my laptop OS: windows XP
4) my office computer OS: windows XP

what can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: run: "route print" from cmd and see where it is sending data destined for your work machines IP/subnet.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. I did it and got a lot of data. What to do with it?

Comment: Look for the IP address of your pc at the office or the subnet at your office and see what it is directing it to. it should look something like: 192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0  The right is where it is routing to the left is the target.

Comment: Thanks, I connect using office's IP and it works fine. What can be the reason? Why does it work fine with computer name from any other wireless network, just not from my home's wireless network?

Comment: Dumb question here but when you try to RDP your system at the office, what are you typing for the target of the RDP session?  Are you using the IP of the system, the NetBIOS name, or the FQDN?

Comment: I don't know looking at your routing table would be the best way to tell whats going on... If you need specific help with that there are many guides online or you can add it to your question/ask a new one.

Comment: Is the machine you are trying to RDP to the same one that you are able to browse c$ on?